# Object reference not set to an instance of an object консольное приложение

Tags: c#

Тип ошибки в шапке. Пишу To Do List в консольке. Смысл моей мысли вот каков:

```
User.cs
У каждого пользователя есть имя.
Каждый пользователь имеет свой список задач.

// code
    internal class User
    {
        private string name { get; set; }
        public List<ToDoTask> Tasks { get; set; }
        public string Name
        {
            get => name;
            set
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append($"User: {this.name}");
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Дальше я подумал создать отдельный класс самой задачи

```
(ход моих мыслей)
Задача имеет имя и у задачи есть пользователь, который её создал.

// code
    internal class ToDoTask
    {
        private string name { get; set; }
        public User User { get; }

        public string Name
        {
            get => name;
            set
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

По итогу словил Exception.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот главный файл `Program.cs`

```
internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            User u1 = new User() { Name = "Michael" };
            var task = new ToDoTask() { Name = "Покормить кота" };
            u1.Tasks.Add(task);

            foreach(var item in u1.Tasks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(u1.ToString());
        }
    }
```

И вот 12 строка, якобы не создан инстанс, только он вроде как создан)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Когда выскакивает ошибка, наведите мышью на объект, который он подсвечивает, посмотрите, что не так, какие он имеет значения, может они NULL. Вот чему равен `u1.Tasks`? Где его инициализация перед добавлением? Не торопитесь задавать сразу вопрос, подумайте, проанализируйте, а уж когда будете думать, что испробовали все, и вы в тупике, пишите вопрос.

Comment: `public List<ToDoTask> Tasks { get; set; } = new List<ToDoTask>();`

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо!